# Facing issue while executing Maven project in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

[start of log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIMsn.png)
[Complete error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zCsZ.png)

Facing issue while executing Maven project in Jenkins. 
Not able to execute project from gitthub.

The error message is reproduced below.

```
O Console Output
Started by user Selvakumar V
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C: \Program Files\Jenkins\workspace\FreeCRMTestProject
Parsing POAs
Established TCP socket on 49852
[MavenProjectGitl] $ java -cp "C:\Program Files\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven33-agent-3.3.9/conf/logging" \
jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main E:\Java\SeleniumDava\Jars\apache-maven-3.3.9 \
"C:\Program Files\Jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-3.29.jar" \
"C:\Program Files\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven33-interceptor-l.13.jar" \
"C:\Program Files\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-l.13.jar" 49852
<===JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven: -B -f D:\MavenProjectGitl\pon.xml Clean Install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] 
[INFO] Building MavenProjectúitl 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] 
[INFO] Total time: 1.749 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-l1-05T19:59:08+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/17M
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "Clean". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or
<plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-
sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-
sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre
integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site,
post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -x switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException
[JENKINS] Archiving D:\MavenProjectGitl\pom.xml to MavenProjectGit/MavenProjectGitl/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/frlavenProjectGitl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: "Clean" != "clean"

Comment: The error message is trying to tell you something. But instead of trying to understand it, better make a screenshot and upload it here?

Comment: @azurefrog could you please explain more

Comment: "Clean" and "clean" are not the same string. One is a valid lifecycle phase in maven, and the other is not.  I'm not sure how to be more clear.

Comment: Thanks @azurefrog. I resolved the issue and my Maven project executed successfully in jenkins.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text - it helps no one and does not (usually) get you help. Paste text as text and mark it as "{}" a text block. Others can't search images (and @F1sh 's sarcasm does not translate either.. Does it not look like a better question now that it's been edited? Also, please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

As @azurefrog explained rather tritely explained via the comment, `"Clean" != "clean"`, Jenkins, Maven and Linux are all **case-sensitive**, that's why "Clean" does not match one of the "Available lifecycle phases", hence the error message:

`Unknown lifecycle phase "Clean".`

```
Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, preintegration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy.
```

The maven lifecycle documentation does not explicit point that it, but the pom settings does imply that under **[Properties](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties)**

> Note: While environment variables themselves are case-insensitive on
>   Windows, lookup of properties is case-sensitive. In other words, while
>   the Windows shell returns the same value for %PATH% and %Path%, Maven
>   distinguishes between ${env.PATH} and ${env.Path}. The names of
>   environment variables are normalized to all upper-case for the sake of
>   reliability.

Also, please read my comment to your question. And if you find this answer useful, mark as "answered" (the tick-box).